# Dependency list of an eclipse plugin project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-luna

I am developing an Eclipse (Luna 4.4.1) plugin project. And I store the project on a remote git server. However I noticed that dependency info of the project does not included on the git server. I also cannot find where this info is stored on local files.

On Eclipse IDE, I can reach this list via clicking on plugin.xml and then dependency tab. With a text editor I opened plugin.xml, build.properties, contexts.xml even .project and there is nothing related to dependency list. Where is this info stored?

Without this, others cannot pull and work on the plugin without getting the dependency list via email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies are in the 'MANIFEST.MF' file in the 'META-INF' directory.

The 'Require-Bundle' entry contains the entries you specify on the 'Required Plug-ins' table of the Dependencies tab. 'Import-Package' contains anything you specify in the 'Imported Packages' section.